# Can you install windows 7 on an IBM x3250 M4 server?

Tags: windows-7, ibm, ibm-xseries

We are running an experiment on our available x3250 M4 Server for the purpose of trying to reach a client's requirement.

Basically they want Windows 7 running on the server.

I want to know if this is possible(without the use of VMWare of course) and how can we achieve this?

When I booted the installer in the dvd rom and finally clicked "Install Now", it displayed this screen:

[image]

"A required CD/DVD Drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD/DVD or USB Flash Drive, please insert it now."

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes possible. Use the exact same process as for 2008R2 Server. Your server should have come with a Driver CD or installation preparation disc. If not, download the driver from IBM's website.

Comment: Only caution would be that you won't get far with IBM support since it isn't on the supported OS list for the server.  So if a drive dies, etc. then think about what you'll say before you call. :)

Comment: Hi Chris, Do I have to download all the drivers from the IBM site?

Comment: Oh..I managed to use IBM ServerGuide, and when it is time to insert the installation cd I put in the Windows 7 installer and it is now currently installing. :D

I think this might just work. Thank you.

Comment: Just an update... I've first installed windows 7 using the 64 bit installer..but then it won't boot to desktop and just keeps on rebooting during the "Starting Windows" thingy..

so i decided to install a 32 bit installation...and it worked perfectly fine. An SM Bus Controller Driver was missing and all I did was install the intel chipset utility program and it everything is ok afterwards.


Installation of Windows 7 in IBM System X servers, as Chris suggested, is done using the ServerGuide. 

Just also make sure that you already had RAID configured before installation :)

Thanks again Chris!

Answer (score 0):

OK I've done it now too.  Win 7 64 bit.  I used Chris S method 2008 R2 with ServGuid 9.50 I mirrored two Samsung 840 EVO SSD's, 8 GB RAM.  ServGuid 9.40 shows no joy.

I have now upgraded the EUFI to 1.7 so next I can install an E3-1240.
The EUFI would not update with out the Integrated Management Module 2 (IMM2) Update

I have not had any issues with the USB.
There is a disabled device IBM USB remote NDIS Network Device #2.
I have yellow warning on the SM BUS controller.

This is used 24 x 7 as a desktop workstation in a 911 call center.
And the third x3250 used for this purpose.