# x3250 M4 reboots when you remove a usb device like keyboard or mouse

Tags: ibm, ibm-xseries, server-setup

Following the installation of Windows 7 in our test server IBM x3250 m4,([Can you install windows 7 on an IBM x3250 M4 server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/525296/can-you-install-windows-7-on-an-ibm-x3250-m4-server)), the server reboots everytime a usb device is removed..if it is attached nothing happens but when you remove it will reboot.

Sometimes when it reboots it displays an error something about 3xPOST ERROR..

I assumed this happens when it reboots and is not properly shutdoown. so I just wait for it to reboot again normally.

What exactly happened? What is the probable cause for this? After installation I downloaded the Intel SM Bus Drivers available for it's chipset which is Intel C202 and installed it in the server.

It removed the warning from the device manager and then this reboot situation happened.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Following the installation of Windows 7 in our test server IBM x3250 m4

This is a bare-metal install of Windows 7 on this server and it's not running in a hypervisor? If so your issue is likely related to the use of a operating system that is not supported and thus not certificated as compatible for your hardware.

If you review the [Installation Guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/bb1ewmst.pdf) you'll find that the `3XPOST ERROR` codes are related to keyboards. My guess is that the USB implementation in Windows 7 is not working with the server's BIOS implementation leading the act of an USB device being unplugged to be interpreted as a keyboard IO controller error which in turns causes Windows 7 to crash. But this is just an educated guess. IBM could probably tell you more or they would if you were using a supported operating system.

> How can I fix this?

Run a supported operating system. If you have a requirement for Windows 7 instead of something more suitable like Windows Server I would recommend you install VMWare ESXi and then run Windows 7 in a virtual machine. If you want to continue with the bare-metal install of Windows 7, investigating basic [Windows Debugging](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2008/11/01/how-to-debug-kernel-mode-blue-screen-crashes-for-beginners.aspx) may yield something useful (presuming this is a kernel-mode crash).